# Should I always add `screen` to `@media` query? Everything appears to work with or without `screen` condition

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm learning responsive design and I've been messing around media queries.

Does anyone know if I absolutely need to use `@media screen`? When writing queries to make my design responsive everything works WITH or WITHOUT `screen`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 99.9% of cases out there, `screen` is all that's ever used to view your site, so could be left out - when not specified, `all` is implied. However, there are other possibilities out there.

Think visually impaired users, for example. Some visually impaired web surfers use screen readers, which do not visit your site as `screen`. There are also tactile web browsers that present information from sites as Braille. Again, not a `screen`.

As mentioned before, these are certainly anomalous users; however, depending on the traffic you expect on your site, it's encouraged as best practice to include the `screen` in your `@media` queries when designing for a screen display.

Other media options are:

- braille
- embossed
- handheld
- print
- projection
- speech
- tty
- tv

### Update (June 2017)

As of Media Queries 4, much of this was simplified—all but a few of the above are deprecated. Currently supported are the following:

- all
- print
- screen
- speech

See the [@media page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) on the Mozilla Developer Network for details, and thanks to @romellem for pointing out these changes!

Comment: Great answer kitty bang!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! I had the same question when I was first learning about `@media` queries. More than happy to share what I found.

Comment: Some of these are deprecated. As of [**Media Queries 4**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#media-types), you should only use:  `all`, `print`, `screen`, `speech`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to use `screen`. It is simply a media type selector which will only apply the styles for the media types that match. For example, if you said `@media print` it would only apply the styles when printing the document.

It all depends on how you want it represented on different medias. When omitted, it applies to all media types.

Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries:

> Unless you use the `not` or `only` operators, the media type is optional and the `all` type will be implied.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep going without `screen` then as it just works everywhere.